# Tag synonym request

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Please synonym [virtualisation](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualisation) to [virtualization](https://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/virtualization).

Answer (score 2):

*Bamf*

Have a tag-merge! On me.

Answer (score 2):

Really? No way, can't we spell things properly or must we drag ourselves down to the lowest (very) common denominator? And on their "independence" day too for goodness sake!

Comment: took the words out of my mouth ;) Unfortunately since I do a fair amount of coding and scripting, I've become accustomed to spelling things incorrectly. Colour particularly

Comment: I'm only kidding of course, happy independence day to all USA-SFers.

Comment: You're just sore losers  =P